# sublime3 laravel how to find which implementation of a class was used

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3

This one is very basic. I am using Laravel5.4 and my editor is sublime text 3. 
While checking codes in the application i am finding it hard to determine which class is being referred to in the **use** statements.

Say below is a code sample:

```
//File name: ModelNotFoundException.php

<?php

 namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

 use RuntimeException;

 class ModelNotFoundException extends RuntimeException
 {
  ..
  ..
  ..
 }
```

As you can see it uses **RuntimeException**. If i hover the mouse pointer over this line i get below popup that shows all the definitions of this **RuntiemExceptoin**:

```
Definitions:
  vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Exception/RuntimeException
  vendor/symphony/console/Exception/RuntimeException
  ....
  ....
  ....(and so so)
```

My question is how do i figure out which one of these classes is actually being referred to here. In the above example, i tried to find a *RuntimeException* class in the **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent** namespace, but there was none.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If no path is specified, php will look for the class in your current namespace (which in your case is "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent") if not found, it will look in the global namespace (im fairly certain it does it in this order, please correct my if i'm wrong). If the class isn't found either, an exception will be thrown.

So, given there is a class, you can find it in your current namespace or in the global one.